Маршрут на карте leafleat
Есть карта Leafleat, я на ней вывел маршрут по координатам. Нужна ещё линия которая показывала бы ширину пройденного маршрута. Ну то есть например была 5м условно на карте. И при приближении и отдалении толщина меняется как сделать так, что бы она не менялась?

при скроллинге пересчитывать ширину линии

@Komdosh, я понимаю, а как от этого избавиться?

В плане? Избавиться от чего, от кода, который будет менять линию?

@Komdosh, ну что бы она не пересчитывала ширину

А, это я не так прочитал. А в чём там ширина?

Суть в том, что вы отдаляете карту, а линия она как бы фиксирована на карте. Вот готовые решения: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/202392/change-width-of-outline-for-leaflet-map-depending-on-zoomlevel

@Komdosh, а есть таблица сколько должен быть weight на метр для каждого зума?
